# Can a class's ivar be an instance of its superclass?

Tags: objective-c

If `ClassB` is a subclass of `ClassA` would it be okay if one of `ClassB's` ivars is an instance from `ClassA`? Sorry, if this is a dumb question. I just find it confusing how `ClassB` inherits from `ClassA` but it could own an instance of it.

Comment: Consider that every object has NSObject as a superclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's good. You can have any type of ivars in any class, basically.

Comment: In some languages it can get a little touchy if you try to make a *subclass* of A be a member of A.  Dunno about Objective-C -- never needed to try it.

Comment: @HotLicks yes, but we're not speaking of other languages, Obj-C only. If you forward-declare the subclass using `@class SomeSubclass` that must be perfectly valid (still not good practice, though).

Comment: Yeah, I would expect it to work in Obj-C, since it's duck-typed and doesn't attempt to maintain a class inheritance map.  Just never tried.  (And even if it didn't work officially you could fake it with a superclass pointer -- this is true of pretty much any language.)

Comment: @HotLicks very good point! Fortunately, Objective-C is well-designed and there's rarely a need to hunt for hackish solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

That's totally fine. A class can even have an ivar of it's own type.

Let's say you have a class Wagon and want to model a train. Your Wagon class probably would have 2 ivars of type Wagon. One that points to the next wagon in the train and an other for the previous wagon.

You could then implement a PassengerWagon subclass of Wagon and it would inherit the Wagon ivars from it's super class. To be clear: you could also only define the ivars (of type Wagon) in PassengerWagon instead of the super class, if you only want to track the neighbors of PassengerWagon instances, but those neighbors can be of any Wagon type.